# Ugee Graphics Tablet - Driver Creation

Tags: 14.04, drivers, graphics-tablet

Is any techie guys out there able to create a driver for this tablet, Ubuntu 14.04 recognizes it, Buttons work on pen and tablet, however cursor wont move at all, Anyone up for the challenge?

Comment: Can you give the model of your Ugee tablet?

Comment: Sorry it's the m708?

Comment: Ah, alright. I'll see what I can do. It took me a while to create the driver for my U-M1000L.

Comment: @AndrewFischer - could you share that driver? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [DIGImend project](http://digimend.github.io/tablets/Ugee_M708/) is dedicated to exactly this task. If you join the [mailing list](http://digimend.github.io/support/#maillist) and help out with information and testing, together we might be able to get it working, if you go to the tablets page you can see just how many tablets the DIGImend project has enabled to work on linux. I'm currently using their driver for my Huion H610.